# SQL - How to count the number of subscriptions in table1 and join datas from table2

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I Have 2 tables:

TABLE 1 (Subscriptions)

```
ID - NAME - COURSEID - STATUS
1  - JOHN -    1     - 0
2  - MIKE -    1     - 0
3  - JANE -    2     - 0
4  - PAUL -    1     - 1
```

TABLE 2 (COURSE Description)

```
COURSEID - COURSE - NAME   - UNIT
1        - EXCEL  - BASIC  - XYZ Street
2        - WORD   - MASTER - ABC Street
3        - PPOINT - BASIC  - MNO Street
```

I need this:

RESULT TABLE:

```
COURSEID - COURSE - NAME   - UNIT       - TOTAL SUBSCRIPTIONS WITH STATUS = 0
1        - EXCEL  - BASIC  - XYZ Street  -   2
2        - WORD   - MASTER - ABC Street  -   1
3        - PPOINT - BASIC  - MNO Street  -   0
```

I TRY LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT TABLE2.COURSEID, TABLE2.COURSE, TABLE2.NAME, TABLE2.UNITY COUNT(*) TOTAL FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID GROUP BY TABLE1.ID
```

But I got only the courses with subscription.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will do what you want. It uses conditional aggregation (the `SUM` of a `CASE` statement) to determine the number of subscriptions with a status of 0.

```
SELECT c.COURSEID, c.COURSE, c.NAME, c.UNIT, SUM(CASE WHEN s.STATUS = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Subs_with_0_status
FROM table2 c
LEFT JOIN table1 s ON s.COURSEID = c.COURSEID
GROUP BY c.COURSEID
```

Output:

```
COURSEID    COURSE  NAME    UNIT        Subs_with_0_status
1           EXCEL   BASIC   XYZ Street  2
2           WORD    MASTER  ABC Street  1
3           PPOINT  BASIC   MNO Street  0
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6e8c3/2)

Comment: Hi @Nick! First of all, tks for sharing your precious time and knowledge to help me. That's it! Tested here and Works fine. I'll upvote and mark you in a few minutes (need to wait more 5 minutes) :D